# How to add Azure Container App adding to a VNET

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-apps

Can anyone show me the YAML used to add a "Azure Container App" to a VNET.

NOTE: This is an **Container App** not Web App or Container Instance (brand new GA).

I am updating my YAML to include the VNET, 'Az containerapp update' runs without failing, but the container is not added to the VNET.

```
az containerapp update --yaml scripts/containerapp/containername.yaml --name containername --resource-group development
```

Comment: VNet integration/injection is not supported as of today - this will most probably come in future releases

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @jul_DW for the comment.

I can confirm that "Container-Apps" do not currently support VNET integration :(

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/3

Comment: VNET support is in preview now. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-container-apps-virtual-network-integration/ba-p/3096932

Answer (score 0):

You can now bring your own VNET as describe here:

- [Networking architecture in Azure Container Apps - Custom VNET configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/azure/container-apps/networking#custom-vnet-configuration)

Looking at the [YAML examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/azure/container-apps/azure-resource-manager-api-spec?tabs=yaml#container-app-examples) for container app, I dont think it is possible to specify the custom VNET in YAML as the VNET is configured at the managed environment level.